# Disable import of video in portrait orientation

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

We have a simple video app where we do not allow users to shoot in portrait. We allow import of videos shot outside the app but would like to block import of video shot in portrait if possible. Would appreciate any help on this!

```
  @IBAction func importVideoTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    imagePickerController.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    viewController.navigationItem.title = "Videos"
}
```

Comment: What are you using to let the user import a video? Show some relevant code.

Comment: added code to original question. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can't filter the videos that appear in the picker so that only landscape videos are available for selection. So, you'll have to let the user select a video, check if it's landscape, and show an alert otherwise. Something along the lines of the following:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    guard
        let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL,
        let videoTrack = AVAsset(url: url).tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first else
    {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

    let size = videoTrack.naturalSize
    let transform = videoTrack.preferredTransform

    //Check if video is in landscape orientation (left or right)
    if (size.width == transform.tx && size.height == transform.ty) || transform.tx == 0 && transform.ty == 0 {
        //TODO: store video however you want for later use
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid video", message: "Please select a landscape video", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        picker.show(alert, sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Make sure to adjust the implementation in whatever way is appropriate to you, and to properly store the video or its url.

Comment: I didn't think it would be possible to filter etc. so this is a great solution! Thank you.

Comment: Glad to have helped! If this solves your problem, please consider accepting/upvoting the answer as it may help others find a solution if they have a similar problem in the future.

Comment: If the user picks the wrong type of video, just show the alert but don't dismiss the picker view. Give the user a chance to select the proper type.